# fail2ban flushing my existing IPTABLES rules

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-12.04, fail2ban

I just implemented `fail2ban` on a server for testing purposes.  I have a BLACKLIST chain which blocks a huge set of CIDR masks that I don't want to reach my server.  When `fail2ban` is triggered by a bruteforce attack, it does add the offending IP address properly, however it flushes out my BLACkLIST chain, which I need to keep intact.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can persist the BLACKLIST chain?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use shorewall as your firewall? If yes, you might want to change the action of fail2ban to `shorewall` instead of `iptables` in jail.conf:

```
...
[ssh-iptables]
enabled = false
...

[ssh-shorewall]
enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
action   = shorewall
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log                                                                    
maxretry = 5
....
```

Comment: Actually no I'm not using a shorewall setup.  The box is a single Linode VPS instance using `iptables` for firewall rules.  Am I doing something wrong?  I can get fail2ban to ban an IP and add an `iptables` rule in the chain and flush it after the ban timeout, but it also flushes my `blacklist` chain that I created.

Comment: You should rather use `/etc/hosts.deny` for blacklisting, then. Most modern daemons, including the openssh package on most distributions, use tcpwrapper. Fiddling with iptables is something you should only do if you ***really*** know what you are doing.

Comment: I'm comfortable with `iptables` and have been using it for years and have custom chains blocking large CIDR blocks from accessing our server on all ports/protocols.  I'm just trying to figure out why `fail2ban` is flushing my preconfigured chain set.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because of the name? Have your tried to change it? Maybe to PREBLACKLIST? However, using tcpwrappers isn't a poor mans solution. Actually it is perfect for exactly your purpose, as changes are immediate and easily scriptable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into tcpwrappers to block the traffic I want to avoid.  I'd still like to get fail2ban to work properly.